# apt install failed due to dpkg interrupt

Tags: apt, nvidia, package-management, dpkg

When I type the command `apt install zsh`, it outputs:

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

When I type the command `dpkg --configure -a`, the output is:

```
Setting up nvidia-430 (430.64-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.6) ...
update-alternatives: warning: forcing reinstallation of alternative /usr/lib/nvidia-430/ld.so.conf because link group x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf is broken
mv: cannot move '/usr/bin/nvidia-cuda-mps-control.dpkg-tmp' to '/usr/bin/nvidia-cuda-mps-control': Device or resource busy
update-alternatives: error: unable to install '/usr/bin/nvidia-cuda-mps-control.dpkg-tmp' as '/usr/bin/nvidia-cuda-mps-control': Device or resource busy
dpkg: error processing package nvidia-430 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Setting up runit (2.1.2-3ubuntu1) ...
Connection to 210.22.22.135 closed by remote host.
Connection to 210.22.22.135 closed.
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: You have to run the commands with `sudo ` ... as in `sudo dpkg --configure -a`  and `sudo apt install zsh`  because the commands needs elevated / root rights

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm in a docker on a server, I try the ```sudo```, but it shows the same error